# Sending mail using SMTP in python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I have a problem on how will I use this

```
    SMTP.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg[, mail_options, rcpt_options])
```

Here's my code:

```
    import sys
    import os
    import re
    from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP
    from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

    SMTPserver = 'server.me.com'
    sender =     'from@yyy.com'
    destination = 'to@yyy.com'
    recipient = ['rcp1@aaa.com', 'rcp2@aaa.com', 'rcp3@aaa.com']

    USERNAME = 'user'
    PASSWORD = 'pass'
    text_subtype = 'plain'
    content='This is a test for mail sending'
    subject='Test'

    try:
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg = MIMEText(content, text_subtype)
        msg['From'] = sender
        msg['To'] = destination
        msg['Cc'] = ', '.join(recipient)
        msg['Subject']= subject

        conn = SMTP(SMTPserver)
        conn.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
        try:
            **conn.sendmail(sender, destination, msg.as_string())**
        except Exception, exc:
            sys.exit( "connection failed; %s" % str(exc) )
        finally:
            conn.close()

    except Exception, exc:
        sys.exit( "mail failed; %s" % str(exc) )
```

Is this a right syntax or code? What I want is that I also wanted to send mail to the list of recipient but where should I put it in the code?

Comment: Please be more specific than 'I have a problem'. What problem do you have? Can you tell us what error you get?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much ok. Have you actually tried using your code (see also the comments)?
The only thing you need to be aware of is that `destination` in conn.sendmail() needs to be a list, so `[destination]`. Then, you can easily replace that by `recipient`, since that's already a list.
There are some good examples here: http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html#email-examples , and your code is pretty much the same as in those  examples.

When you've run your code and get an actual error that you can't solve, you're welcome to come back here and ask a new question.